# Safari Web inspector keeps disconnecting

Tags: debugging, safari, osx-yosemite, safari-web-inspector

I've **Safari 8.0.6** with **iOS 8.3** on my iPad, while debugging through Web Inspector on my **Mac (10.10.3)**, the connection keeps on disconnecting (I don't see the device name under Develop menu upon disconnection) but can resume if I quit safari followed by a relaunch then I'm able to refresh and inspect remotely again.

Comment: This seems to be a very common problem. Some people have suggested changing the cable, I have not had any luck with that though. When this happens to me I just unplug and replug the cable in the iPad, it is a bit quicker and slightly less annoying than restarting Safari.

Comment: @enifeder thanks for the comment, and yes changing cable didn't help me either, I was wondering earlier if there's some javascript error that breaks the connection

Comment: Happens to everyone constantly. It's a Safari bug.

Comment: It appears this issue has been resolved with the release of Safari 9.0.  I was experiencing the issue repeatedly yesterday but after installing Safari 9.0 today I haven't seen Safari disconnect while debugging my cordova app

Comment: I am experiencing this with Safari 10.0...

Comment: I have the same problem with both Safari 10.1.2 and Safari Technology Preview 11.1. Both running on a macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: This is indeed a problem that happens very frequently; ensure that both MacOS and iOS on your device are up-to-date is a good thing to do first. Most of the time, updating to the latest makes debugging work again.

Answer (score 75):

There are a few things to try:

### 1. Test on the Xcode Simulator:

> Open the iPhone simulator in Xcode and debug there with Safari Web Inspector.

**Sidenote**: Maybe you need to download the [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/)

### 2. Reset your location and privacy settings on your device.

> Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy

### 3. Debugging on a real device

With this configuration it seems to work right now.

iPhone X, iOS Version 12.1.3
macOS Mojave Version 10.14.2 (18C54)
Safari Version 12.0.2 (14606.3.4)

**Edit 2019.08.13**

> Settings -> Safari -> Advanced -> Check that Webinformation is toggled on.

It was suddenly toggled off and I couldn't connect via the Web Inspector. After toggling it on, it worked.

**For other devices / versions, please read further down (Maybe you can decrease your build size).**

---

**EDIT: 2018.09.20**

@Chet found out, the Web Inspector keeps disconnecting for too large JS files and map files

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52338231/4641479

Issue on Github:

https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy/issues/275

https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy/issues/274

I could confirm this on a real device with a production build (1.8 MB + 2.4 MB files), the Safari Web Inspector stays always connected.

[image]

Since for the development build it is not:

[image]

---

Before my web inspector very rarely worked and often just stopped working - but was still open. After the safari update the web inspector opens and closes immediately. If you encounter such problems..

This will work:

## Step 1. Get the latest Safari Browser

Safari: 11.1 (12605.1.33.1.2)

https://developer.apple.com/safari/download

macOS Sierra and OS X El Capitan (I assume macOS high Sierra is also supported)

Maybe you need to download the [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/)

---

## Step 2. Reset your location and privacy settings

On your device go to:

> Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87181

---

## Step 3. Connect your device

Open Safari on OS X
If you had connected your iPhone device with an usb cable, disconnect it first.
Now plug it in.

On OS X Safari go to:

> Develop > Device name > Apply for development

Now on your phone there is a permission question. Choose trust and now you can choose the open tab on your devices safari and debug.

---

## Happy debug!

Now the web inspector stays connected.

Comment: I thank you so much really!! *Step 2.* worked for me like charm <3

Comment: Worked for the first time but after that same problem again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51224913/694609 Emptying Cache fixed this problem for me!

Comment: There is no "Developers" menu item for OSX Safari

Comment: @AlxVallejo Go to Preferences -> Click on the Advanced Tab -> Down there `Show Develop Menu in Menu Bar` (If you meant my misspelling, you could've just corrected it, translation mistake - my safari browser is not english)
Here are pictures: http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/03/enable-the-develop-menu-in-safari/

Comment: "Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy" on device worked for me!

Comment: resetting location and privacy settings

Comment: Step 2 fixed it for 5 minutes :') 
Don't developpe IOS app !

Comment: Step 2 used to work for me, but not anymore :(, is there any update on that issue ?

Comment: Step 2 worked. IOS15.2 (iPhone SE2)

Answer (score 51):

Do you have a lot of backgrounded apps running on your iPhone?  Kill them and try again.

We showed this issue to Apple developers at WWDC, and they suspected it was due to memory constraints on the iPhone.  Sure enough, killing most of our backgrounded apps resolved the issue for us.

Comment: Amazing, I didn’t really hope for this option, but it helped

Comment: So both the Reset Privacy of the accepted answer, and this one seem to work for me. However, it's nice to do this rather than reset privacy settings to have to constantly be nagged then by every.single.app to allow something.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me in August 2021. I thought I was going to need to download the developer version of Safari.

Comment: I only get one app open, the one to debugged.

Comment: whaou this works !!

Comment: This & the "Reset Location & Privacy" also worked for me! (iPhone 11, iOS 15.1)

Answer (score 32):

## Working Solution (as of 24th Mar 2020)

Well, after so many trials and opening thousands of blog posts to figure out a solution, I managed to get it working without a single case of failure.

For me, this has been always a problem with my Ionic+Cordova application.

My subconscious mind started to think about this problem when I saw that this issue (of Safari getting disconnected) is not there when I run a plain simple Cordova or Ionic application. And then suddenly, I tried another thing and it worked.

Basically, the Safari web inspector disconnects when the size of any files are too large (not sure about the limit). Maybe, some image, some script, and CSS. In my case, it used to because of the JavaScript & their source map files.

So, when I started to run my iOS application without source maps, the problem is gone. For that, all I had to do is to pass `--source-map=false` to my `ionic cordova commands` like:

```sh
ionic cordova run ios --source-map=false
ionic cordova run ios -lc --source-map=false
```

I wrote a small article about this to elaborate this in detail https://medium.com/wizpanda/a-small-tip-to-speed-up-development-with-angular-or-ionic-d5764f639c0c

## Original Answer

Most of the answers listed here worked for me for a while but after a few hours they also stopped working and my Safari web console again keeps disconnecting as it opens.

Other few options that worked for me:

### Option 1 - Empty Cache From Safari

`Safari on MacOS -> Develop -> Empty Cache`

### Option 2 - Clear Trusted Computers

`On iOS Device -> Settings -> Developer -> Clear Trusted Computers` then reconnect the USB cable and then try to debug again

### Option 3 - Make the debugger fool (as of 14th Jan 2019)

This solution is working for a long time now. Since this is an issue related to connection between iOS & Mac so I opened my **Console** app and just kept my iPhone selected. (This is somehow kept my iOS device connected to my Mac)

Then opening the Developer's console on Safari worked fine for me without disconnecting.

### Option 4 - Run via Xcode

This is also a kind of workaround and a hack to see it functional. You can basically prepare your iOS app by `ionic cordova prepare ios` and then run the app using Xcode and deploy it to your iPhone.

At least, I'm able to see the console logs and sometimes, it even works with Safari web inspector.

### Option 5 - Run on iPhone simulators

I think this is the most working solution. This option is suitable when your system is not running too many applications as firing a simulator suckup a good amount of system resources.

Basically, instead of running your app on a real device, run your app in an iPhone simulator via Xcode and debug it normally in your Safari web inspector and this problem will not occur.

This is probably because the files being transferred to Safari inspector is from the system itself.

Comment: Emptying the cache fixed it for me too.

Comment: The third option seems the most reliably for me so far.

Comment: 3rd one is guaranteed. Console is available on your macOS, use spotlight.

Comment: Second option immediately worked for both of my devices (5s and Xs).

Comment: Option 3 seems to be a life saver to me - the idea to get connected even having bigger sourcemaps is to first connect to any small app on the device and only then switch to another app/tab on same device.
Thanks!

Comment: Tried all of them and none worked :/ I regret developing for IE6

Answer (score 10):

Sounds strange but it may be happening due to the battery being full triggering a disconnect: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/92290

> The disconnection seems to occur when the battery of the Iphone is full. (So for the moment we turn the flash and the camera on to kill the battery while inspecting ...)

Comment: This is likely why you came to this SO post. The answer above helped me.

Comment: I thought this was the culprit for me, but it wasn't. So beware this might not be the problem.

Answer (score 10):

*This is only necessary for physical devices. Physical devices can be forcefully disconnected by Safari if the device's battery is full. ("Full battery? Well then, let's just disconnect you as you don't need to charge anymore -- and there goes your debugging session too...")*

You will want to select **Connect via Network** in `Develop > [device]`, and then attach your debugger to the page you want to debug. If you do not have the **Develop** menu in Safari, go to `Safari > Preferences > Advanced` and select **Show Develop menu in menu bar**.

[image]

If this doesn't work, you may try upgrading your OS/Safari through the App Store first.

If things are **still** breaking, disconnect your iOS device. Go into your iOS device into Settings > Safari > Web Inspector and turn it off and then back on. Force quit out of Safari. Re-plug in your iOS device and start up Safari again and re-attach your iOS device through Safari > Develop menu.

Comment: via Network worked for me. On Safari v11.1.2 iOS 11.4.1. It was crashing immediately without the network option. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Closing XCode first helped for me.

Answer (score 2):

This plagued me for a long time with very inconsistent behaviour, here are a few things I have found that help, I also wrote a blog post on this [here](http://idesignpixels.com/safari/ios/osx/xcode/2018/02/22/fix-safari-web-inspector-disconnecting/).

1. Update both mac safari and ios - I have found after having the latest of both versions it started working for me, there could be debugging incompatibilities between Safari's.
2. Check that web inspector in ios is enabled - It has been known that this setting can be switched off after an upgrade, check in settings > safari > advanced > web inspector.
3. Check the port you are connected to - I have had mine plugged into a cheap hub / via apple keyboard/monitor hub and found that going directly into the mac works much better.
4. Are you using a good quality cable? - I have found that better quality / official cables that aren't worn out have better reliability when in debug.
5. Other notable observations - other people have commented that making sure cookies are enabled in safari, enabling private mode and trying whilst Xcode is open have affected the reliability of this, although I haven't seen this myself it may help others to try.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say I have a solution, but a step in the right direction.

I tried using [ios-webkit-debug-proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy) so I can use the Chrome Dev Tools instead of Safari Dev Tools.

Note, in order to get it to work, I can to upgrade my iOS to the latest 11.4.1 and MacOS 10.13.65, then reinstall the latest versions:

```
brew update
brew install ios-webkit-debug-proxy
brew reinstall --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew reinstall -s ios-webkit-debug-proxy

ios_webkit_debug_proxy
```

After running `ios_webkit_debug_proxy`, I was able to try to connect through `chrome://inspect` and it disconnected immediately again:

```
Listing devices on :9221
Connected :9222 to Chet's Phone (6a028994cf281be807bf80c5557c3f2eb3fbb8b0)
Invalid packet header 0x1ffffff91ffffffa0ffffff9d == .... == 26321053
Disconnected :9222 from Chet's Phone (6a028994cf281be807bf80c5557c3f2eb3fbb8b0)
```

However, we have a clue! `Invalid packet header`. Sounds like a lower level bug somewhere. Not sure where to submit this but to though...

Comment: Sit down to track this error down with the Console App and had also some new insights, I will update my post above

Comment: I was able to create a reproduction for [ios-webkit-debug-proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy/issues/274) and it seems relevant to this issue because the reproduction was consistent with the Safari Web Inspector issue. It appears to be an issue with the javascript source size when unminified with sourcemaps.

Comment: You're right! Thank you! With a production build with the AOT compiler of angular, with a size of 1.8 MB for a main.js and a 2.4 MB vendor.js with no sourcemap files, it works all the time, with Xcode connected and without. I would still like to debug my development build, though.

Comment: Yeah, me too. I have 39MB unminified js file I'm dealing with 

Comment: I can confirm that removing the sourcemaps fixed this for me.

Answer (score 2):

**The magic solution worked for me:**

1. Reboot your MAC
2. Reboot your iPhone

Comment: rebooting iphone only thing that works at least for a while

Answer (score 2):

**09-07-2020**

Still this issue on Latest MacOs (Catalina 10.15.5) on Safari (13.1.1)

**Solution on Ionic/Capacitor:**

```
ionic cap run ios -l --external --source-map=false
```

Answer (score 1):

The most recent Safari Technology preview appears to have solved it for me.

https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/

Comment: Starting from `Safari Technology Release 42 (Safari 11.1, WebKit 12605.1.10)` seems that the problem is resolved

Comment: Didn't change anything :(

Comment: Now the inspector opens.. and in a second (sometimes more or less) it now closes, instead of being open and just nothing happens like before. Still it is closing right now and can not figure out why. Safari Desktop Version 11.1 (12605.1.33.1.2) => Sierra

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Safari Technology Preview didn't helped

Comment: Still have this problem with Safari Technology Release Release 70 (Safari 12.1, WebKit 14607.1.13) so I don't think this answer is valid!

Comment: Release 72 still having the issue

Comment: 3 years later, Safari TP still has this issue

Answer (score 1):

### MacOS Mojave / Catalina Solution

For me the issue started right after I upgraded to the new macOS Mojave, this might have been mentioned somewhere above but for me I just needed to download the new "Safari Technology Preview" app that is built for Mojave.

**Safari Download Page**

https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/

**Direct Download for Mojave**

https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/STP/041-71285-20190604-6d0dcb17-07e5-40a0-b418-dba732cefe64/SafariTechnologyPreview.dmg

Answer (score 1):

For me using a different adapter and cable solved the problem.
Every time you connect, it should ask for "Trust this device" like prompt on smartphone, if not then it's the cable/adapter issue.

Answer (score 1):

When using a content-blocker (e.g. 1Blocker) on your iOS device, make sure it is disabled for the domain you want to debug.

Disabling 1Blocker stopped the Web Inspector (Mac) from closing immediately after opening it, and allowed me to get back to work.

Answer (score 0):

I know there's a lot of answers already, but I wanted to post because none of them worked for me just now. But, my phone's battery was in "low mode" ... but since I'm plugging it up for development, I didn't think that was a big deal. But, going into settings on my phone and turning off low battery mode fixed my problem. Now safari doesn't disconnect.

Just wanted to post that in case someone runs into this with a low battery.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for ionic app:

```
ionic cordova build ios --source-map=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been seeing this issue when using live preview in Capacitor while building an Ionic Angular project on macOS Monterey previewing on iPhone Xs. Here are a few ways I can get over this bug and continue development...

1. Make sure you're using [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) and not the regular version of Safari.
2. Close and Re-Open Safari Technology Preview if it continues. You could also try inspecting using regular version of Safari after installing Safari Technology Preview. It may work for debugging almost as well.
3. On your device, open the app switcher and close all background applications before starting development on your app.
4. Toggle 'Connect via Network' in Safari on your computer by using: Develop > Device Name > Connect via Network in the Safari menu.
5. Disconnect and reconnect the lightning cable of your device. Make sure it has a steady firm connection to the computer. Off-brand cables can cause intermittent development issues.
6. Quit your app, go to the app switcher and force close your application by swiping it away. Then re-open it using the app icon in the launcher. Try inspecting it again.
7. Try rebooting your computer and rendering your app again. After a lot of up-time there may be some built-up log data that needs to be dumped.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable sourcemaps from being read in Safari.

1. Open the web inspector
2. click the cog to open settings
3. Go to the sources tab
4. Uncheck "Enable source maps"

This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

## Capacitor, Ionic, Cordova

`rm -rf platforms/ios/**/*.map`