# iPad connected through USB disappears off Safari Develop menu after a short while on iOS 11

Tags: ipad, safari, macos-sierra, ios11, safari-web-inspector

iPad is on iOS 11, trying to debug using safari develop menu. I am using a MacBook Pro 2016 on MacOS Sierra. The iPad name appears in the develop menu for about 5 seconds. After this time it disappears.

If I unplug the iPad and re-plug it, the name appears, again, only briefly. Then it disappears again.

Anyone sharing the same issue? Any fixes would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 11):

Solved it. Make sure Safari on your Mac is the same version as Safari on your iPad.(iOS version is same as Safari version on iPad)

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: How do you find out the version on the iPad? TIA

Comment: @greg "(iOS version is same as Safari version on iPad)"

Comment: Good to know... gah, this means every time we update our dev iPad we have to update our dev Mac along with it.

Comment: carrying out a pending os update in iphone did it for me. Btw, in my case, the iphone name did show in the `Develop` menu but on loading the web inspector for the relevant ios safari tab, the inspector only stayed for a few seconds and then disappeared.

Answer (score 7):

The correct solution is described here:

[Safari Web inspector keeps disconnecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251938/safari-web-inspector-keeps-disconnecting)

1. Make sure both Safari on your tethered device and machine are up to
   date
2. Disconnect
3. On your device go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location &
   Privacy
4. Re-connect

Answer (score 1):

Connect your iPhone or iPad to your Mac. And then open the Activity Monitor app (Applications > Utilities), or you can use Spotlight.

When you open the App, enter usbd in the search field. And the force quit the process by clicking the X sign.
(This is taken from https://macreports.com/iphone-keeps-connecting-and-disconnecting-from-mac-fix/)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem with a very large unminified JS bundle (unminified for faster rebuild time while developing). I got rid of the bundled sourcemap and minified the file, and Safari was able to handle it. It's not an ideal solution, and it only works if the minified file doesn't hit whatever threshold Safari has for blowing up, but it's something.

Answer (score -1):

you can try to this the IPad needs to be on the same internet and open the command line to get the ip-address.type the ip-address on the search bar of your IPad and add the semicolons with the port number like this=>   192.62.45:3000. this will load on the index page.if this is not working check your fire-walls that are not blocking the connection turn them off.hope i  helped.

Answer (score -1):

**On iPAD**

Go to Settings --> Safari --> Advanced

and turn on 'Web Inspector' (toggle on).

Comment: This problem only happens after you're past that step.